# Number in Numbers from list in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, integer

I have an array[11,12,13,14,15] . My task is to complete the Function num which returns an integer denoting the total number of times digit k appears in the whole array.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: Please don't forget to post your `code` and where do you have questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = [11,12,13,14,15] 
l = [str(i) for i in l]

"".join(l).count("1")
```